# Codeigniter 3 cookies not working on the server

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

my code is working perfectly fine on the localhost but it's not working on the server.

Below is on the home function

```
$this->input->set_cookie('ci_sm', 'test', 86400);
```

And I'm try to read this from another page/function

```
echo get_cookie('ci_sm');
```

Of cause the library is loaded via autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('cookie');
```

Testing this on a Ubuntu server but it doesn't seem to work.
Any help if you have come across this issue.

Comment: Is it generating any error?

Comment: No errors are generated

Answer (score 3):

Here is my suggestion that may help to overcome this issue:

For site-wide cookies regardless of how your site is requested, add your URL to the domain starting with a period, like this: `.your-domain.com`

The structure of `CI`'s `set_cookie` function is:

```
$this->input->set_cookie($name, $value, $expire, $domain, $path, $prefix, $secure);
```

So your final `set_cookie` function will be like this:

```
$this->input->set_cookie('ci_sm', 'test', 86400, '.some-domain.com');
```

Comment: Thank you Mahbubl, adding the domain info to the cookie did the trick.

Comment: I removed the "." (dot) of the domain name. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

> Load the helper either in your config file by default or in your
>   controller.  You can follow my code sample by creating an array and
>   setting the value with whatever data.

```
class Cookie_controller extends CI_Controller { 

      function __construct() { 
         parent::__construct(); 
         $this->load->helper(array('cookie', 'url')); 
      } 

      public function index() { 
      } 

      public function display_cookie() { 
            $cookie = array(
                'name'   => 'data',
                'value'  => '21',
                'expire' =>  92000,
                'secure' => false
            );
            $this->input->set_cookie($cookie); 
            var_dump($this->input->cookie('data', false)); 
      } 


   }
```

Hope this helps